# Why are interfaces necessary in MVP design pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, interfaces, winforms, mvp

I am trying to understands MVP using Winforms.

I found this [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14660/WinForms-Model-View-Presenter). Why do UserModel and UserView need to implement the IUserModel and IUserView interfaces ?

Comment: [Why using interface for Presenter in MVP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25579295/why-using-interface-for-presenter-in-mvp)

Comment: MVP? Most Valuable Player?

Comment: Model View Presenter.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter)

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's a bit of a different question.

Comment: Perhaps.  But the answer is exactly the same.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You should have just answered this question.

Comment: In general, the reason interfaces are used here are the same reasons you would use an interface anywhere else.

Comment: I meant answer the question (not in the comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interfaces are required in good quality implementations of MVP for the same reason they are required in all good "OO" designs:

1. They help reduce coupling
2. They discourage inheritance (which further reduces coupling)
3. Arguably most importantly, they simplify unit test writing

Comment: In some languages they're also your only option for multiple inheritance e.g. C#